# If statements without the if

Tags: javascript

I was reading a code that shows how to use the logical && operator making "if" statement.

```
someBoolean && (someStatement = 10);
```

is equal to :

```
if(someBoolean) {
someStatement = 10;}
```

I know how && works. But I couldn't understand how it works like an if in this example.

**&& operators works like this : If the first value is false, it will be returned, else it will search until it can find a false value. If no, the last value will be returned.**

In this example, if someBoolean is false, "someBoolean" will be returned! Else the "(someStatement = 10)" part will be returned.

But it is exactly the opposite of "if". Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's one not very readable way to do it. The logical AND operator only goes to the right side if the left side is true.

Comment: You didn't read my question well!

Comment: @AmirJalilifard Perhaps, but I think you're not exploring what adeneo said completely. It's just an expression that happens to have an assignment on one side.

Comment: How is it opposite of `if`? It can only get to the next item if `someBoolean` is `true`. In the same way the `if` statements condition must be true to set `someStatement`.

Comment: It's the same as the `if` statement you posted *in this case*, but it's not the same thing, it's not even the opposite thing, it's just different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But it is exactly the opposite of "if". Isn't it?

No, it turns out to have the same effect as an `if` statement.

If the first operand (`someBoolean`) is false, then that value is used for the whole expression, and the second operand (`someStatement = 10`) is not evaluated as it is not needed.

If the first operand is true, then the second operand has to be evaluated to determine the value of the whole expression.

Answer (score 4):

The key to using logical statements is understanding [Short-circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (which you allude to in your question).  To be precise, nothing is "returned" - but I think you mean it is "evaluated to" - but since the result is not captured, this evaluation will be lost.

But this approach to an "if" isn't interested in the final result, it is simply using the short-circuit evaluation in order to conditionally evaluate the second part of the expression if the first part is true.

So, some examples:

- `x && (y = 10)` : Only assigns 10 to y if x is true
- `x || (y = 10)` : Only assigns 10 to y if x is false
- `!x || (y = 10)` : Only assigns 10 to y if x is true

This style is hard to read of course, so generally not recommended for source code. Though I see it in minified code often, as it saves a couple characters.

Comment: Great explanation, especially the inclusion of short-circuit evaluation, minified code, and examples.

Answer (score 2):

It works like an if in the sense that after the first expression evaluates true, the second is evaluated. Opposite of that, if the first exprssion evaluates false, the second expression will not be evaluated. In my example below, the value for b is never assigned because the second if starts with false &&. You will see 'undefined' in the second alert.

```js
var a;
if(true && (a = 10))
    alert(a) //alerts 10

var b;
if(false && (b = 5))
    alert(b) //never alerts b/c of the false above
        
alert(b); //alerts undefined b/c (b = 5) is never evaluated
```

Answer (score 1):

If `someBoolean` is true the rest of the expression will evaluate, which is `(someStatement = 10)`.

Values aren't "returned" by `if` statements, they're *evaluated*.

This method ignores the result of the expression, which is fine.

I wouldn't use it; it's a bit more cognitive overhead. That's just an opinion, though.